# Create another symbolic link from symbolic link in Debian by mount --bind ... command

Tags: linux, files, mount, bind-mount

I have got question how to create symbolic link from another symbolic link (with mount --bind command) under Debian.

**They are two cases:**

**First case:**
I have got core data in /main/data. And in the folder "data" are some files(folders, files etc.).
Where I created symbolic link to another folder such as:

> mount --bind /main/data /user/admin

and next create another symbolic link not from core folder but from admin folder such as:

> mount --bind /user/admin /public/user1

All work fine, because I created symbolic link of folder to folder **BUT** second case:

**Second case:** I want mount only single file from /main/data (by using mount --bind command such) as in first case. At first to admin and after mount whole folder to /user/admin to user1. At first I will need create blank file in /user/admin and after to mount core file. Steps under work good - **example:**

> touch /user/admin/myNewFile.txt
>
> mount --bind /main/data/information.txt /user/admin/myNewFile.txt

But last part are not working - **example:**

> mount --bind /user/admin /public/user1

Last command mount folder from /user/admin to /public/user1 which cause mount all files and folders place in /user/admin. In /public/user1 will appear "myNewFile.txt" but this file is blank with 0 size.

Question is if there is any option of mount command to mount correctly or if there any other solution of this problem.

Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mount --bind` command creates *bind mounts*, not symbolic links; actual symbolic links are created using the `ln -s` command.

When you use `mount --bind /main/data/information.txt /user/admin/myNewFile.txt`, you are attaching a part of one filesystem (specifically, one file) on top of another filesystem. Although the contents of `information.txt` now appears at `myNewFile.txt`, that still does not make that file a part of the `/user/admin` *filesystem*. Usually it wouldn't matter, but for your last command, it will.

`mount --bind /user/admin /public/user1` makes a bind mount of a *single* filesystem - any submount points within the original are not replicated... including the submount point `/user/admin/myNewFile.txt`.

If you want to replicate an entire directory tree using bind mounts, *including any existing submounts* like your `/usr/admin/myNewFile.txt`, then you must use `mount --rbind` instead:

```
mount --rbind /user/admin /public/user1
```

---

Your second case is analogous to what would happen if you did first:

```
mount --bind /main/data /user/admin
```

and then:

```
mount --bind /user /mnt
```

If you did this, you would probably find that `/mnt/admin` will be an empty directory. (Or if there are some files, you would find they are certainly not the up-to-date files from `/main/data`, but some old junk from way back when someone tried to use `/user/admin` without making sure `mount --bind /main/data /user/admin` was done first.)

When you make a regular mount, or `mount --bind` for a directory, you must first `mkdir` an empty directory at the destination. The mount command will then attach something else on top of that directory. Likewise, when doing `mount --bind` for a single file, you must first `touch` an empty file at the destination, so the mount command will have something to attach to. If you then `mount --bind` that part of the filesystem, those underlying empty directories/files are what you will see instead of the mounted filesystems/files in the original.

Comment: to telcoM: Thank you very much for exhasuting answer. You helped me a lot. Thanks